# Echo php Image in modal from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want the image to appear in the modal div. 
When I use target="_blank" or any other attribute it works but I want the image the modal div 
Here is the code

```
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT Name, Email, Address, Sex, Image FROM members";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row=$result->fetch())
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Name']?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['Email']?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['Address']?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['Sex']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Image']?></td>
            <td><a href="upload/<?php echo $row['Image']?>"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">View Image</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

</table>
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content" style="height:20em">


       </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div>
     </div>

  <script>
    $(function () { $('#myModal').modal({
    keyboard: true
    })});
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code for the specific problem, but **only** relevant code - nothing more. Your problem is about HTML/Javascript, not PHP specifically. The database query is completely irrelevant. But if anybody is to help you, it would be nice to know what JavaScript library you're using to create a modal.

Comment: @JohannesMüller I am using bootstrap library and I want to echo image in the div (modal) the image is in an upload folder stored in the database. I want to use target (thus HTML href attribute) to put the image in the div. When I use target blank it works but is not working for the modal!!

Answer (score 0):

add the `modal` div tag within the `while` loop and insert the image source there

Comment: I tried it but is not working!! Maybe is either I got it wrong or I couldn't understand you properly !!